# Power led is not up when powering from power bank?

Tags: usb-power

Is it normal that red led (power one) is off when Rasberry is connected to power bank instead of original power adapter? Got 23000mah power bank that gives 5.1V/2.1A on USB... checked it out, and it really does. Thats pretty annoying... any way to fix it?

Comment: If the red LED is off, presumably the pi is off.  Check if your new powerbank has a button on it somewhere.  Plugging something into mine isn't enough -- I have to turn it on, and then some LEDs on the bank also come on.

Comment: But it is on, i can see it on monitor... web server is running... etc etc.

Comment: And when you use a normal wall adapter the red LED *is* on?   Yeah that's odd.   Which pi is it BTW?

Comment: Yes, normal power adapter makes red led to light. Pi 2.